# Find Contacts with no Relationships

Tags: contacts, api, relationships, searchkit, cli

Have tried using API, but 
`$result = civicrm_api3('Contact', 'get', array(
      'return' => "id",
      'contact_sub_type' => array('!=' => "Parent"),
));`

gives zero results, while Search builder gives results using this query:

`Contact Subtype Not Like Parent ...AND...
Contact Type = 'Individual'`

API calls also give zero results count if

```
 'organization_name' => array('IS NOT NULL' => 1),
```

and

```
'current_employer' => array('IS NOT NULL' => 1),
```

being used, although we know such records exist. Moreover, theree are records, where "Current employer' field is empty, which yet have Relationships.

In theory, it might be possible to compare two arrays (all existent Relationships wjere Contact A is an Individual and all existent Individuals), but it might be tricky a bit at current number of records in both arrays (around 100K in each).  So, any reliable way to find Individual Contacts  with no Relationships, nor Employers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thing which works is  "**include/exclude custom search**" : "Search -> Custom searches -> Include / Exclude Search" or **/civicrm/contact/search/custom?csid=4&reset=1** Thanks @Coleman!

Answer (score 5):

One way of achieving your goal would be via a temporary group:

1. Using advanced search, search for all contacts who *do* have a relationship (simply open the "Relationships" tab, enter nothing, and search - it will default to all active relationships).
2. Add all the resulting contacts to a group (or make a smart group if you want to save yourself this step in the future).
3. Using search-builder, find all contacts not in that group.

PS: the "Parent" contact sub-type has nothing to do with relationships. Contact types are quite different in CiviCRM from relationships, and having one does not automatically bestow the other.

Comment: Sorry it doesn't work unfortunately, Search builder still gives contacts with at least one Relationship.

Comment: Try the include/exclude custom search

Comment: Have tried several conditions, one which did the trick  *once(!)* is " Contact ->Group(s) -> Is null ". Thanks God I've added contacts found in a group than; haven't been able to repeat this  since: "Not in group" gives no results (mean, too much results);  no luck with 'Is null' / '≠' / 'Is empty'  as well. Moreover, it gives "random" results: sometimes it;s an empty set, sometimes it's a couple of records..

Comment: Did you try the include/exclude custom search?

Comment: It took me time to realise what "include/exclude custom search" means and where is it. For those who'd be interested, it's here: /civicrm/contact/search/custom?csid=4&reset=1 And this works, thanks! Wish I found it before.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of years after the question was asked, but still a relevant question.

You can find contacts without relationships using the 'without' join in SearchKit:

See [here](https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/admin/search#/create/Contact?params=%7B%22version%22:4,%22select%22:%5B%22id%22,%22display_name%22%5D,%22orderBy%22:%7B%7D,%22where%22:%5B%5D,%22groupBy%22:%5B%5D,%22join%22:%5B%5B%22Contact%20AS%20Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01%22,%22EXCLUDE%22,%22RelationshipCache%22,%5B%22id%22,%22%3D%22,%22Contact_RelationshipCache_Contact_01.far_contact_id%22%5D%5D%5D,%22having%22:%5B%5D%7D)

[image]